# Need to run Curl in background in php

Tags: php

I have set up curl to visit website url in php but I do not want to show url in browser:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        
        
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$rest =curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

But ever time it is showing in url of browser can anybody suggest thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to provide your full code / a minimum reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I need to hit url but I do not want to show on browser above code is working but displaying url on browser